# Align rotation of plane to rotation of other object

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

Right now I am working on knife fighting and I've stumbled upon a small problem.
I am creating a decal on a surface being hit by the knife and I want to rotate said decal to match the rotation of the knife during the hit.

To do that I am using this code:

"transform" is referring to knife's transform

```
    Vector3 point = Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 normal = Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 origin = controller.cam.transform.position;
    Vector3 dir = hitOrigin.position - origin;

    RaycastHit rayHit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(origin, dir.normalized, out rayHit, melee.attackReach, controller.hitMask))
    {
        if (rayHit.collider)
        {
            EHitSurface surface = Utilities.GetSurfaceFromMaterial(rayHit.collider);

            point = rayHit.point;
            normal = rayHit.normal;

            GameObject decal = Managers.instance.hitEffects.PlaceDecalAtPosition(point, normal, EHitType.CUT);

            Quaternion localRot = Quaternion.FromToRotation(-transform.right, normal);

            Vector3 euler = decal.transform.eulerAngles;
            euler.z = localRot.eulerAngles.z + 90;

            decal.transform.eulerAngles = euler;

            Managers.instance.hitEffects.PlaceImpactAtPosition(point, normal, surface);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it gives me different rotations based on the rotation of player in the world, for example: if I hit west wall it will be rotated correctly, but if I hit the north wall it will be rotated by around 30-40 additional degrees.

Here's a short video to showcase the problem: https://gfycat.com/HappyHotAmericanbadger

How would I align the decal to match the knife's attack direction? What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to use *localEulerAngles* instead of eulerAngles. 
If it does not you can use another stable transform as parent for the knive which needs a script to ignore Player rotations.